# Mixpanel: alias on a known user

Tags: javascript, analytics, mixpanel

I can:

- assign a temporary ID to an unlogged user,
- collect events
- use alias to keep track of the user (all the events appear in the mixpanel people section).

My problem is that if

- the user logout, and the cookies gets cleaned out,
- when my user come back I assign a new temporary ID to my unlogged user
- than it logs in again,
- so I use the alias again (with an unknown temp ID and a known user ID) but mixpanel is not able to link that it was the same user again.

These events are lost, they appear nowhere in the people section.

Is it because I explicitly set the distinct_id property of my user (in the mixpanel.track method) ? or it is just not possible to do this operation of tracing unlogged operation and finally realizing that it was a known user ?

Answer (score 2):

If user LogOut there is no way to tie his activity between LogOut and LogIn after cleaning cookies. So this is how Mixpanel's user identification model works together with cookies.

According to Mixpanel documentation - you should use alias() only once in a user lifetime after Signing Up (Registering).

If you use alias() on the last step - Mixpanel will ignore it.
You must use identify() method instead of alias(), but of course Mixpanel will accept only events fired up after indentifying user.

This scenario is described here in Advanced Aliasing: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/using-mixpanel-alias
Their example says about user coming back from Phone insted of PC, but clearing browser cookies means anonymizing (like using another device).

In any general scenario LogOut should not lead to resetting mixpanel's cookies. Can you provide more specific information? Maybe there is a way not to reset them?

For example in my project one device can be used by many users, so this works just fine for me.